# Вывод категорий с книгами в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть две связанные таблицы в базе, вот файлы

models.py:

```py
class Group_books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=18)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    group_books_id = models.ForeignKey(Group_books, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView
from .models import, Group_books

class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"
    #queryset = ''

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['group_books_list']=Group_books.objects.values('name')
```

base.html:

```html
{% for li in group_books_list %}
  <li><a href="">link {{ li.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Нужно вывести после названия категории, список всех книг этой категории.
Как это делается классическим для Django способом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**views**

```
class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Group_books.objects.all()
        return context
```

**html**

```
{% for category in categories %}
  {{ category.name }}
  <ul>
  {% for book in category.book_set.all %}
    <li>{{ book.name }}</li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>В этой категории книг нет</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% empty %}
  Категорий нет
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас испытаю...